# Argumentoutofrange Exception

Tags: c#

I'm getting an Argumentoutofrange exception whenever I try to run a dictionary editor I just made. So far I am just trying to check if a word the user enters is part of a list that is read in from a file, and the logic for the actual dictionary editor and the checking are in two separate files.

Everything works fine until I push the button that starts the checking and the exception comes up when I call the constructor for the checking.

Here is the code for the dictionary editor:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SpellChecker;

namespace DictionaryEditor
{
public partial class DictionaryEditor : Form
{

    public DictionaryEditor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(f_Paint); //Paints the title onto the form
    }

    //Paint handler to make the title
    static void f_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    //Override OnPaint to make the title
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //Call OnPaint
        base.OnPaint(e);

        //Make graphics variable
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        // Get the width of the form to make the title
        int titleWidth = ((this.ClientSize.Width)/2)-100;

        // Get the font for the title
        Font titleFont = new Font("Arial", 25);

        g.DrawString("Dictionary Editor", titleFont, Brushes.DarkCyan, titleWidth, 20);
    }

    private void ExitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void SpellCheckBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SpellCheck spellTest = new SpellCheck();

        string answer = spellTest.CheckSpelling(HeadwordTxt.Text);

        MessageBox.Show("The calculations are complete", "My Application",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
    }

}
}
```

The exception happens on the first line in the SpellCheckBtn event handler at this line

```
   SpellCheck spellTest = new SpellCheck();
```

The constructor for this is found in this code in the SpellCheck file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace SpellChecker
{
public class SpellCheck
{
    private List<string> correctWords = new List<string>(); //List to hold words from the text file

    public SpellCheck()
    {
        string line;  //String to hold a line from the file

        //Make StreamReader and put words into correctWords
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("WordList.txt"))
        {
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                correctWords.Add(line);
            }
        }
    }

    public string CheckSpelling(string theString)
    {
        int i = 0;            //Counter for postion of correctWords

        //loop to check all words
        while (correctWords[i] != null)
        {
            if (theString.Equals(correctWords[i]))
            {
                return "Word " + theString + " is spelled correctly." +     Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version ;
            }

        }

        return "Invalid Spelling";
    }



}
}
```

I've been stuck on this for a long while now, so any help would be appreciated.

Here is the event handler for the button that would check the words in the dictionary editor

```
 private void SpellCheckBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SpellCheck spellTest = new SpellCheck();

    string answer = spellTest.CheckSpelling(HeadwordTxt.Text);

    MessageBox.Show("The calculations are complete", "My Application",
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
}
```

And here is the constructor for the spell check

```
 public SpellCheck()
    {
        string line;  //String to hold a line from the file

        //Make StreamReader and put words into correctWords
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("WordList.txt"))
        {
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                correctWords.Add(line);
            }
        }
    }
```

When the exception is thrown this is at the top of the stack:

```
>   DictionaryEditor.exe!DictionaryEditor.DictionaryEditor.SpellCheckBtn_Click(object sender,     System.EventArgs e) Line 53   C#
```

Comment: Are you really not able to narrow down the code to reproduce this issue to less than what you've posted here?

Comment: I added the two parts that I believe are causing the exception at the bottom of the post and hope it helps. I'm positive the file has all the words in it. It is just one word per line.

Comment: It's the CheckSpelling function that throws it, none of the elements are null, so the while loop will go beyond the boundaries of the array, hence the ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

Comment: I just changed the CheckSpelling to use foreach instead of a while loop, and the issue has not changed. The exception is thrown right when I try to make spellTest

Comment: When an exception is thrown there's usually a message and a stack trace associated with it and Visual Studio usually shows them in Debug mode. Could you post that here?

Comment: Added it to the end of the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CheckSpelling method should be changed to something more 'safe'

```
public string CheckSpelling(string theString)
{
    //loop to check all words
    foreach(string word in correctWords)
    {
        if (theString.Equals(word))
        {
            return "Word " + theString + " is spelled correctly." +     Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version ;
        }
    }
    return "Invalid Spelling";
}
```

You actual code assumes that there is always at least one entry in the correctWords list, and start an infinite loop checking always the entry at index 0. (No increment of the variable i is visible).
Using a foreach will avoid to check the List if there is no entry.

However I will check the code that loads the `correctWord` list. It is possible that your file doesn't contains any word or the words are not correctly separated in different lines or the file that you are opening is not the one that you intend to open (different folders?)

**EDIT**
As you can read in the comments below, it turns out that the problem was the platform mismatch between the two projects that are part of the solution. One project (SpellChecker) was configured for AnyCPU as target platform, while the other (DictionaryEditor) was configured for x86 platform. This scenario causes the strange `OutOfRange` exception. Converting the SpellChecker project to x86 resolved the problem (and viceversa, converting the DictionaryEditor to AnyCPU)

Comment: Wasn't the issue, but I'm now using the for each in CheckSpelling. Still the same error though

Comment: I suggest to use the debugger to check the content of the file and the content of the correctWords at the moment of the spelling call

Comment: It seems very odd that you get the error in the constructor. At least not with that error message. (FileNotFound, Permission, even OutOfMemory but not IndexOutOfRange). I suggest to clean the solution and rebuild (Build -> Clean Solution)

Comment: Keep getting the same error. Even when I comment out the constructors logic, it keeps throwing the exception at the same spot right on the constructor call

Comment: Cleaning the solution and rebuilding everything?

Comment: Yup. Just tried it again and same issue at the same spot.

Comment: Sorry, but I have no more ideas. If the project is not too big and you are willing to share I could take a look at the whole code.

Comment: That's alright. I've been stuck on this for a long time now and thank you for trying to help me. I'd of course be willing to share the code.

Comment: Just to test. Could you remove the code that handles that custom paint? If you wish to share your project please zip and load it on a sharing site like GDrive, OneDrive, DropBox and put the link here. Do not forget the wordlist file.

Comment: Alright I tried removing the custom paint, and it didn't change anything. Here is the dropbox link to the project. The text file is in the bin/debug folders of the two seperate project files: https://www.dropbox.com/s/d2yx3n9dlegebqq/DictionaryEditorProject.zip?dl=0

Comment: Good news and bad news. Good: got the same problem. Bad: no idea why, must be something with the solution or the project. Still trying. What version of Visual Studio?

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. Thanks so much for helping with this!

Comment: FOUND IT!!!!! The project for the SpellChecker targets AnyCPU while the project for the DictionaryEditor targets x86. Passed everything to x86 and now works.

Comment: Where do you change that if you don't mind me asking? I'm still pretty new to visual studio and c#

Comment: Using VS2013, but should be the same. BUILD->Configuration Manager. Then select x86 in ActiveSolution Platform. Then in the SpellChecker line select new and create the x86 platform if not exists and select it. Do not forget to check the Build checkbox.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks so much Steve I don't think I could have done this on my own. People like you are the reason this community has been blowing my mind since I started programming.

Answer (score 0):

The indexer for `List<T>` throws an exception if the index is out of range. You need to check the index is valid before you try access the list at that index.

You need to compare `i` to the `Count` of the list:

```
while(i < correctWords.Count) { ... }
```

or just use a `foreach`:

```
foreach (string word in correctWords)
{
    if (theString.Equals(word))
    {
        return "Word " + theString + " is spelled correctly." +     Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name + Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version ;
    }
}
return "Invalid Spelling";
```

Comment: Was not the issue when I tried this, but I can see how it was going to throw an exception

Answer (score 0):

from the comments above and your replies, I suspect the problem to be in the "HeadwordTxt.Text", especially when you said that you commented the logic of the constructor, can you replace the "HeadwordTxt.Text" with a normal string and try it? so the code would be

```
string answer = spellTest.CheckSpelling("test");
MessageBox.Show("The calculations are complete " + answer, "My Application",
MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
```

Comment: Just tried this and the result is still the same. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: can you tell me which line exactly through the exception?

Comment: The construtor call: SpellCheck spellTest = new SpellCheck();

Comment: I removed the SpellCheck.dll and added the SpellCheck.cs in the DictionaryEditor seems to work fine, this is a pure build problem for the dll